# Using JavaScript for combining two arrays into one object's array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given arrays 
name `['a','b','c']`
data `[1 , 2 , 3]`

I want the result
`[{name: 'a', data: 1}, {name: 'b', data: 2}, {name: 'c', data: 3}]`,

I could do

```
 let combinedData = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     combinedData.push({name: name[i], data: data[i]});
 }
```

but I am looking for an elegant way, shot. (Using external lib is acceptable e.g. lodash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple es6 solution could be:

```
let arr1 = ...;
let arr2 = ...;

let data = arr1.map((item, i) => ({a: item, b: arr2[i]}));
```

Comment: That's not a valid arrow function resulting in a SyntaxError.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've missed the parentheses around the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let name = ['a','b','c'];
let data = [1,2,3];
let combined = name.map((v, i) => ({name: v, data: data[i]}));
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let combinedData ={};
  let name = ['a','b','c'];
    let data = [1 , 2 , 3];
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     combinedData[name[i]]=data[i];
 }
 console.log(combinedData);
```

Comment: I was looking for "[{name: 'a', data: 1}, {name: 'b', data: 2}, {name: 'c', data: 3}]", not {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, thanks anyways :)